# Subscript out of Range - Run time error 9

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

This the code I am trying to run:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
'-------------Declarations-------------------
Dim FinalRow, Sum As Long
Dim i, j, l, d, k, count As Integer
Dim custID(), amtPur() As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Data")
FinalRow = ws.Range("B90000").End(xlUp).Row
j = 0

'-------------Get All the Data-------------------
With ws

For i = 4 To FinalRow
custID(j) = ws.Range("B" & i).Value   'Error Here
amtPur(j) = ws.Range("C" & i).Value   'Error Here
j = j + 1
Next i
End With

'-------------Match it and present the output----
l = 4
Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = Sheets("Results")

With wk
For j = 0 To FinalRow
     Sum = amtPur(j)

    'For the first iteration
     If j = 0 Then
        For k = j + 1 To FinalRow
        If custID(j) = custID(k) Then
        Sum = amtPur(k) + Sum
        Else: End If
        Next k
        wk.Range("A" & 3).Value = custID(j).Value
        wk.Range("B" & 3).Value = Sum

    Else: End If



           'For the rest iterations
           count = 0
           d = j
           Do While (d >= 0)
           If custID(d) = custID(j) Then
           count = count + 1
           Else: End If
           d = d - 1
           Loop

           If count <= 1 Then   'Check if instance was already found

           For k = j + 1 To FinalRow
           If custID(j) = custID(k) Then
           Sum = amtPur(k) + Sum
           Else: End If
           Next k
           wk.Range("A" & l).Value = custID(j).Text
           wk.Range("B" & l).Value = Sum

           l = l + 1


    End If


Next j
End With

End Sub
```

but unfortunately am getting:

> Subscript out of Range - Run time error 9

when I try to run it.

Comment: Could you tell us what line throws the error as there's quite a bit of code here. Also, in VBA you must declare every variable with a type, so I'd suggest changing your code and editing this post. An example is: `Dim i, j, l, d, k, count As Integer` should be`Dim I as Integer, j as Integer ... etc.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, seems a little harsh that this question has been downvoted. You're clearly new to VBA and it does seem that you've given this a fair go. I admire people who learn through trial and error - it's certainly more than many first posters do - so I'd like to give you a pretty full answer with a bit of the theory behind it:

1. `Dim` - as mentioned, declare each type. Avoid names that are similar to existing functions, like `sum`.
2. If you declare your 'read' variable as a variant, you can read the data from the worksheet with just one line and the array will be dimensioned for you. You can also acquire `custID` and `amtPur` in the same array. I've given you an example of this in the code below in a variable called `custData`. Be aware that these arrays have a base of 1 rather than 0.
3. Your `With` blocks are redundant. These are meant to save you repeating the object each time you access its properties. In your code you repeat the object. I'm not a huge fan of `With` blocks but I've put a sample in your code so you can see how it works.
4. Your `If ... Else ... End If` blocks are a bit muddled. The logic should be `If (case is true) Then` do some code `Else` case is false, so do some other code `End If`. Again, I've tried to re-write your code to give you examples of this.
5. You are confusing looping through a `Range` and looping through an `Array`. In your code you have set the limits of the Range as 4 - `FinalRow`. However, this does not mean your arrays have been set to the same dimensions. Most likely, your arrays start from 0 and go to `FinalRow` - 4. You need to be clear about these dimensions before looping.
6. As Mark Fitzgerald mentions, you need to `dimension` your array before using it. If it's an initial dimension then you could just use `Redim`. If you want to increase the array's dimension whilst retaining existing values then use `Redim Preserve`. I've tried to give you an example of both in the code below.

Okay, so onto your code...

With the looping, array size and `If` mistakes, it's rather difficult to see what you're trying to do. I think you might be trying to read all the customer IDs, writing them into a unique list and then summing all the values that match each ID. The code below does that. It's not the quickest or best way, but I've tried to write the code so that you can see how each of the errors above should work. I guess it doesn't matter if I'm up the wrong path as the main aim is to give you an idea of how to manage arrays, loops and `If`s. I hope your `custID` and `amtPur` are genuinely `Long`s - if, for example, `amtPur` stands for 'amount purchased' and is, in fact, a decimal number then this code will throw and error, so make sure your values and declarations are of the same type. Your commenting etiquette is a little esoteric but I've still followed it.

Good luck with your project and keep at it. I hope this helps you:

```
'-------------Declarations-------------------
Dim dataSht As Worksheet
Dim resultsSht As Worksheet
Dim custData As Variant
Dim uniqueIDs() As Long
Dim summaryData() As Long
Dim counter As Integer
Dim isUnique As Boolean
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'-------------Get All the Data-------------------
Set dataSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set resultsSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
With dataSht
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(4, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
End With
custData = rng.Value2 'writes worksheet to variant array

'-------------Loop through the data to find number of unique IDs----
For i = 1 To UBound(custData, 1)

    isUnique = True

    If i = 1 Then
        'First iteration so set the counter
        counter = 0
    Else
        'Subsequent iterations so check for duplicate ID
        For j = 1 To counter
            If uniqueIDs(j) = custData(i, 1) Then
                isUnique = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'Add the unique ID to our list
    If isUnique Then
        counter = counter + 1
        ReDim Preserve uniqueIDs(1 To counter)
        uniqueIDs(counter) = custData(i, 1)
    End If

Next


'-------------Aggregate the amtPur values----

ReDim summaryData(1 To counter, 1 To 2)

For i = 1 To counter

    summaryData(i, 1) = uniqueIDs(i)

    'Loop through the data to sum the values for the customer ID
    For j = 1 To UBound(custData, 1)
        If custData(j, 1) = uniqueIDs(i) Then
            summaryData(i, 2) = summaryData(i, 2) + custData(j, 2)
        End If
    Next

Next

'-----------Outpute the results to the worksheet----
Set rng = resultsSht.Cells(4, 1).Resize(counter, 2)
rng.Value = summaryData
```

Comment: I just pasted this code into your `Module3` and ran it and it worked fine. Just change the third last line `Set rng = resultsSht.Cells(4, 1).Resize(counter, 2)` to `Set rng = resultsSht.Cells(3, 1).Resize(counter, 2)` so that it fits your headers. Try it again and see how you go. BTW type `Option Explicit` as the very first line of the module. Make sure you're calling the correct routine when you run it. To test it, place your cursor anywhere within the routine and hit F5.

Comment: Thank you Very much you are Awesome :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: BTW, suggest you delete that dropbox link or all the world will be able to see your company data.

Answer (score 4):

While you have declared your custID() and amtPur() arrays, they need to be initialised using ReDim statements before you can use them.  In your case you will want to ReDim Preserve to retain values already stored in the arrays during prior loops:

```
Sub Test()
'-------------Declarations-------------------
Dim FinalRow, Sum As Long
Dim i As Integer
j As Integer
l As Integer
d As Integer
k As Integer
count As Integer
Dim custID() As Long, amtPur() As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Data")
FinalRow = ws.Range("B90000").End(xlUp).Row
j = 0

'-------------Get All the Data-------------------
With ws

For i = 4 To 100
ReDim Preserve custID(0 To j)
ReDim Preserve amtPur(0 To j)
custID(j) = ws.Range("B" & i).Value   'Error Here
amtPur(j) = ws.Range("C" & i).Value   'Error Here
j = j + 1
Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @jeeped - I think the redim preserve works fine as an initialisation. Don't know what the docs say, but it works...

Comment: Edited to explicitly declare all integer variables.  ReDim Preserve works as initialisation command in the context of single dimension arrays.  If you wanted to initialise multi-dimensional arrays you would need to use `ReDim custID(0 to 1, 0 to 0)` to allocate the required elements.